# Scrollbar height indicator to execute function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery to get user's current height, and after he reaches that height, there will be animation function (Such as reactive websites, when user scroll down he has animation in different part of the page).

Yet, I can't really figure out why exactly the following code doesn't work.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(height  > 200) {
      $("#project").animate({
        bottom: '250px',
        opacity: '0.5',
        height: '1000px',
        width: '100%'
      });
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
/*       About Page        */
.about{
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: blue;
}
/*       Projects Page        */
.project{
  background-color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
    <title>My Portfolio</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="about" class="about">

    </div>
    <div id="project" class="project">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I use scrolling height indicator to activate functions such as animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take into account the height of each section and calculate the `scrollBottom` position instead, which might be more useful if you want to trigger an animation once you reach some element:

```js
const $about = $('#about');
const $projects = $('#projects');
const $services = $('#services');

// Calculate the top offset of each section (number of sections above it * 1000px each).
// We want to expand them when we are 50px above them, so we substract that.
let projectTop = 1000 - 50;
let servicesTop = 2000 - 50;

$(window).scroll(() => {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    // Calculate the scrollBottom by summing the viewport's height:
    const scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

    if (scrollBottom >= projectTop) {
      $projects.animate({ height: '1000px' });
    }
    
    if (scrollBottom >= servicesTop) {
      $services.animate({ height: '1000px' });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.about {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}

.projects {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
}

.services {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="about" class="about"></div>

<div id="projects" class="projects"></div>

<div id="services" class="services"></div>
```